# How to prevent CVS from converting line endings?

Tags: windows, unix, cvs, line-endings, vcs-checkout

Like many other people we're having line ending issues with CVS. However, unlike most our problem is the opposite.

Is there a way to force CVS to *not* convert lines from /n to CR/LF. I would like the line endings to remain in the Unix format even if I checkout to a Windows machine. Is that even possible?

The problem: the conversion of the line endings is causing checkums to change, which is an issue because then it is hard to compare the equality of two deliverables (they are not auditable in any other way).

Moving from CVS to SVN is not an option (not from lack of trying)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tag the files as binary with `-kb` and CVS won't mangle line endings.

```
cvs add -kb new.file
cvs admin -kb existing.file
```